# MySQL: Privileges to view Views/Stored Procedure for user Regardless of Host

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, permissions, mysql-5.6

I've created stored procedures on a (remote hosted - [DreamHost](https://www.dreamhost.com/)) MySQL Database using the [HeidiSQL](https://www.heidisql.com/) client.

One problem i seem to have is that viewing/editing the content of stored procedures is only possible when connecting from the same "host".

For example, i connect primarily from home, via a BT connection (I'm a BT customer)

But when i try connecting in from work (a different provider/ISP) i can do everything, run queries, edit tables etc, but cannot edit/view the Views/Stored Procedure queries despite connecting with the same username.

I'm assuming the "@") may be something to do with it?

Is there anyway i can prevent this from being a problem?

Comment: `GRANT ... TO 'user'@'%' ...;`

Answer (score 0):

You may check grants for user and see if it differs for hosts.
In addition to

```
show grants for username@host
```

You may check grants for specific databases:

```
use dbname;
show grants for username;
```

Also, there are few more places to check for extensive list of privileges:

```
SELECT * FROM FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.USER_PRIVILEGES
WHERE GRANTEE LIKE '%userame%';
SELECT * FROM FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_PRIVILEGES
WHERE GRANTEE LIKE '%userame%';
SELECT * FROM FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMA_PRIVILEGES
WHERE GRANTEE LIKE '%userame%';
```

Most likely  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.USER_PRIVILEGES will shed a light on your issue.